# 'str' object has no attribute 'field' using widget_tweaks

Tags: python, django

This question has been up tons of times, but are all narrowed down to exactly their specific issue. I hope that this question can clarify the problem more, so it will become more generally useful, than just narrowed to my issue.

I get the error `'str' object has no attribute 'field'`

And I got following code

```
template.html

{% load widget_tweaks %}

<form action="." method="POST">
  {% render_field form.co_nip_number name="co_nip_number" class="form-control" type="number" required="" %}
</form>
```

```
forms.py

from django import forms
from .models import BusinessContact


class BusinessContactForm(forms.Form):

    class Meta:
        model = BusinessContact
        fields = 'co_nip_number'
```

```
models.py

from django.db import models

class BusinessContact(models.Model):
    co_nip_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
```

```
urls.py

from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'dashboard'

urlpatterns = [
    path('new-client/', views.NewClient.as_view(), name='new-client'),
]
```

```
views.py

from django.views.generic import FormView
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import BusinessContactForm


class NewClient(FormView):
    template_name = 'dashboard/new-client.html'
    form_class = BusinessContactForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()
        return HttpResponse('You managed')
```

```
TRACEBACK

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jannicklangkjaer/PycharmProjects/penge/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/jannicklangkjaer/PycharmProjects/penge/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 145, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/jannicklangkjaer/PycharmProjects/penge/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 143, in _get_response
    response = response.render()
  File "/Users/jannicklangkjaer/PycharmProjects/penge/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content
  File "/Users/jannicklangkjaer/PycharmProjects/penge/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 83, in rendered_content
    return template.render(context, self._request)
  File "/Users/jannicklangkjaer/PycharmProjects/penge/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "/Users/jannicklangkjaer/PycharmProjects/penge/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 171, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "/Users/jannicklangkjaer/PycharmProjects/penge/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/jannicklangkjaer/PycharmProjects/penge/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/jannicklangkjaer/PycharmProjects/penge/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/jannicklangkjaer/PycharmProjects/penge/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 150, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "/Users/jannicklangkjaer/PycharmProjects/penge/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 163, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/jannicklangkjaer/PycharmProjects/penge/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/jannicklangkjaer/PycharmProjects/penge/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/jannicklangkjaer/PycharmProjects/penge/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 62, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "/Users/jannicklangkjaer/PycharmProjects/penge/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 936, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "/Users/jannicklangkjaer/PycharmProjects/penge/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/Users/jannicklangkjaer/PycharmProjects/penge/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/widget_tweaks/templatetags/widget_tweaks.py", line 220, in render
    bounded_field.field.widget.input_type = v.resolve(context)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'field'
```

What does this error mean? How do we solve it?

Thank you for your time

Comment: What is the traceback?

Comment: @nog642 added. My bad

Comment: You are not using form correctly, Please make following changes in your `forms.py` 
replace `class BusinessContactForm(forms.Form):` with  `class BusinessContactForm(forms.ModelForm):` Secondly replace `fields = 'co_nip_number'`     with `fields = ('co_nip_number',)`

Please update your code with above changes and share your result. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found two mistakes in your `forms.py` code.

1. You are using `Form` instead of `ModelForm`
2. You are setting fields with `string` but it needs to be set with `tuple` or `list`

Please update your `forms.py` code with following code

```
from django import forms
from .models import BusinessContact


class BusinessContactForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = BusinessContact
        fields = ('co_nip_number',)
```

I have tested the above code, It resolved the issue and successfully renders the field.

Comment: I knew about the tuple or list, but I actually removed all fields but one for simplicity, and PyCharm suggested this way. :)